# Refactor a verbose switch case statement

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I have an object that keeps weather measurements for a single factory.

```
public class FactoryWeather { 

    // each measurement consists of min, max and average observations.
    private Measurement temperature;
    private Measurement humidity;
    private Measurement ...

    public constructor,setters/getters...

}
```

Measurement types are defined as enum like below :

```
public enum WeatherMeasurementEnum {
    // min and max range of single measurement
    TEMPERATURE(-50,50),
    HUMIDITY(0,100),
    ...

    // validity check for measurements
    public boolean isValid(int average) {
        return average >= minimum && average <= maximum;
    }
}
```

Finally, I update each measurement using following method :

```
public void updateWeatherMeasurement(String type, Measurement measurement, FactoryWeather factory) {
    WeatherMeasurementEnum m = WeatherMeasurementEnum(type.toUpperCase());
    if(!m.isValid(measurement.getAverage())
        throw new AppException("Invalid measurement!");

    switch(m) {
    case TEMPERATURE: factory.setTemperature(measurement);break;
    case HUMIDITY: factory.setHumidity(measurement);break;
    ...
    }

}
```

Although the switch statement might look fine, type of measurements can grow in future. Taking this into consideration and the sake of best practice, is it possible to eliminate this kind of long switch or if/else statements ?

Comment: Have you learned about the Stategy Pattern?

Comment: I don’t think you’ve told me enough that I can say whether this will work, but I’ll air the idea: in `WeatherMeasurementEnum` add a method `setMeasuremet(FactoryWeather)` that in turn calls the correct method in the factory. It will require an abstract method in the enum and an implementation in each enum instance.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having a separate field in FactoryWeather for each measurement, you could have a `Map<WeatherMeasurementEnum, Measurement>` storing the measirement for each enum instance.

You would then just have to do

```
public void updateWeatherMeasurement(String type, Measurement measurement, FactoryWeather factory) {
    WeatherMeasurementEnum m = WeatherMeasurementEnum(type.toUpperCase());
    if (!m.isValid(measurement.getAverage()) {
        throw new AppException("Invalid measurement!");
    }

    factory.setMeasurement(m, measurement);
}
```

And in fact, this method could be eliminated completely, since the `setMeasurement()` method of FactoryWeather could validate the measurement validity directly.

Another option is to delegate the setting of the field to the enum itself:

```
public enum WeatherMeasurementEnum {
    // min and max range of single measurement
    TEMPERATURE(-50,50) {
        @Override
        setMeasurementInFactoryWeather(Measurement m, FactoryWeather fw) {
            fw.setTemperature(m);
        }
    },
    HUMIDITY(0,100) {
        @Override
        setMeasurementInFactoryWeather(Measurement m, FactoryWeather fw) {
            fw.setHumidity(m);
        }
    },
    ...

    // validity check for measurements
    public boolean isValid(int average) {
        return average >= minimum && average <= maximum;
    }

    public abstract setMeasurementInFactoryWeather(Measurement m, FactoryWeather fw);
}
```

Although it may seem more verbose than the switch statement, it has a huge advantage: there is no way you can forget to handle setting the measurement when a new type of measurement is introduced: the compiler will force you to implement the abstract method.